# Upload of data not populating $_FILES

Tags: swift, upload, alamofire

I've been experiencing some issues to upload a file to a server using Alamofire.

The files are uploaded well, but the variables where the upload should appear are empty : FILES:array(0) {\n}\nPOST:array(0) {\n}\n

And using the website, we can upload images without any problem

Would anyone have an explanation or a solution to my problem?
(the file size is not an issue, I send a 370kb image and the limit is 20mb)

```
func postImages(images : [UIImage], compression : CGFloat, completion: ((AnyObject?)->())? = nil) {
        AlamoNoCache.manager?.upload(.POST,
            "\(MYURL)/upload?access_token=" + "youwontknowit",
            multipartFormData: {
                multipartFormData in
                for (index, image) in images.enumerate() {
                    multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, compression)!, name: "file", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
                }
            }, encodingCompletion: {
                encodingResult in
                switch encodingResult {
                case .Success(let upload, let streamingFromDisk, let streamFileURL):
                    print(upload)
                    print(streamingFromDisk)
                    print(streamFileURL)
                    upload
                        .progress({
                            a, b, c in
                            print("\(a), \(b), \(c)")
                        })                
                        .responseString(completionHandler: {
                            a in
                            print("\(a)")
                        }
                    )
                    break
                case .Failure(let error):
                    print(error)
                    break
                }
        })
    }
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I used this with Alamofire for upload any kind of files:

```
let request = alamofireManager.upload(.POST, remoteURL, headers: httpHeaders, file: fileUrl);
```

and if you want to handle the response:

```
request.response {(request, response, object, error) -> Void in
...
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't change anything :/
FILES:array(0) {
}
POST:array(0) {
}

Comment: Same as before, it uploads, as the progress shows, but still $_FILES and $_POST are empty